# search word in multiple websites with different structures using import.io

Tags: web-crawler, extract, import.io

I have a list of more than 10.000 websites and I would like to search for a keyword in all of them.

The expected result should be something like the link and a column with values of 1 if the website contains the keyword and a 0 if it doesn't.

Is there any way to specify a list of websites and a keyword to search for using import.io?

Answer (score 0):

Import io does best when each site you're crawling has a similar structure. If you're set on using import io,

1) Put all the website links into a column

2) Use the "bulk extract" option of an "extractor" type API to pull out all the text from each page and put that into a column.

3) Open the exported excel or google spreadsheet, and use the "find" function to see if your keyword is contained in each cell

With that said, I think you may have better luck using a different web scraping service since you're not actually looking to extract content.